Combining 3D Mapping with RTAB-Map and 2D Mapping with Hector SLAM on Jetson Nano in ROS Melodic
I'm new to ROS and Jetson Nano, and for our final year project, we need to develop an autonomous vehicle. One of our key tasks involves running SLAM algorithms to generate a map of the environment.
So far, we’ve managed to:
Generate a 3D map using RTAB-Map with an Intel RealSense D435 depth camera on the Jetson Nano.
Generate a 2D map using RP Lidar A1 with Hector SLAM.
However, our main challenge is combining both of these maps. Our goal is to simulate in RViz so that we can display:
A 3D map created using RTAB-Map with the D435 camera.
A 2D map created using Hector SLAM with the Lidar.
We need these to run simultaneously on a single screen without any lag or disturbance.
All of this is running on a Jetson Nano B01 (4GB) with Jetpack 4.6.5, Ubuntu 18.04, and ROS1 Melodic.
If anyone has experience with this or knows the steps to achieve it, please share the details. Clear, step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated so that others facing the same issue can follow along easily.
Thanks in advance!
#ROSMelodic #RTABMAP #HectorSlam #JetsonNano #Rviz
